# Sips command in Terminal not working - "Error 4: no file was specified"

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, terminal, sips

Trying to resize some imgs for web project direct from command line. I'm no terminal expert, but I normally use `sips -z maxWidth# nameofimg.jpg"`

What I typed here:

```
mycomputer$ sips -z 650 slideshow1.jpg
Error 4: no file was specified
Try 'sips --help' for help using this tool
```

I am in the correct directory, and have a file name slideshow1.jpg in there. What else could be going wrong? Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) we can see that there are two versions, `-z` and `-Z`.

```
sips -z pixelsH pixelsW
sips -Z pixelsWH
```